# Populate an attribute table field using the 'startswith function

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I am hoping that someone may be able to help me.  I am new to ArcGIS, and even newer to Python.

Working in ArcGIS 10.1, I have done is created a new text field in an attribute table, which I have called "Ag".  I want to populate this field with the text from another field (called Address) which is in the same attribute table BUT only if that text starts with the word "Field".

I have written the following function but it is not working, and I am not sure where I have gone wrong, or if I am on the wrong path completely.

```
def Reclass(agri):
    if (!Address!.startswith("Field")):
      return !Address!
    else:
      return "NA"
```

I have searched the forums and the ESRI documentation for a solution, but cannot seem to find what I am looking for.  I hope that I have given all the relevant information for someone to be able to help me with my conundrum, but please let me know if there is more (or better) information I should supply.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Replace *!Address!* field with your input parameter *agri*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I wasn't sure if you meant to change the !Address! in the "if" line or the "return" line.  I tried both & in both cases I was thrown the error _"Parsing error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"_.  I understand this is an issue with whitespace, but I have double-checked my indentation & cannot see the problem (2 spaces on the "if"/"else" line and 4 on the "return" line).